# Shopify GraphQL Mutation Doesn't Work In CURL Or Postman But Does With GraphiQL App

Tags: curl, graphql, postman, shopify, graphiql

When I'm using the following mutation in **GraphiQL App it works** perfectly but when I run it using **Postman** or **CURL** it just **doesn't work.** This issue is **happening** for **Function** related **mutations** **only**.

**The Mutation:**

```
mutation {
    discountAutomaticAppCreate(
      automaticAppDiscount: {
        title: "Volume Discount Created from APP 011", 
        functionId: "9d8aas8-78asd-8d7sa-86f0-dg789asdfa9sd", 
        startsAt: "2023-09-19T00:00:00"}
    ) {
      
          # Payload
          userErrors {
              code
              field
              message
          }
          automaticAppDiscount {
              discountId
              title
              status
              createdAt
              endsAt
          }
      
    }
  }
```

The error that I get when using CURL or Postman:

```
"data": {
    "discountAutomaticAppCreate": {
        "userErrors": [
            {
                "code": "INVALID",
                "field": [
                    "automaticAppDiscount",
                    "functionId"
                ],
                "message": "Function not found."
            }
        ],
        "automaticAppDiscount": null
    }
}
```

The Functions that I'm using to make the CURL request(Though it's not that important as this is just working fine for many other queries):

```
public function makeGraphqlApiRequest($data)
{
    $storeName = 'store-name';
    $apiVersion = '2023-07';
    $accessToken = 'access-token';

    $graphqlEndpoint = "https://$storeName.myshopify.com/admin/api/$apiVersion/graphql.json";
    
    $headers = [
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "X-Shopify-Access-Token: $accessToken"
    ];
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graphqlEndpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        return 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    
    curl_close($ch);
    
    return $response;
}
// End makeGraphqlApiRequest Method
```

Later I rechecked the "shop-name" and "api-version" both in GraphiQL and CURL, Postman. They all had same shop-name and api-version.
What can I do to solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: can you show us your CURL requset

Comment: @HardikSatasiya I've added it in the post though it's not that important as this is just working fine for many other queries.

Comment: you also need to deploy stuff `yarn deploy`. your function ID is correct means it should be from your .env file.  can you double-check it

Comment: I've double checked everything related to this query. Besides the loads of other queries and mutations are working perfectly using this curl fnc and same goes for the postman variables.

Comment: hmm, so I guess it's not an issue of CURL, somehow that function is not found so it's not able to get deployed correctly. hmm